# Cron every 5 minutes 8h to 20h

Tags: cron

I searched for 15 minutes and to me the syntax still isn't clear...
would this:

```
*/5 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 * * *
```

run the job every 5 minutes from 8(8am) to 20 (8pm)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

search no more, just type in shell `man 5 crontab` and read...

hint:

`*/5 8-19 * * * /path/script`

per @madhatter comment, you should add another job

`0 20 * * * /path/script`.

Comment: That will run the job up until 2055h; the OP is probably better off with `*/5 8-19 * * *  /path/foo`, and a separate line to deal with 2000h.

Comment: @madhatter thank you for pointing this out for me)

Comment: No worries; have a +1 from me!

Comment: you're too kind, sir (have one from me as well)